# Grep selected files having date and time as file name

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have the following files in `/home/download/file` on Linux:

```
Abc_05-29-2022_12:30:01
Abc_05-29-2022_12:40:01
Abc_05-29-2022_12:50:02
Abc_05-29-2022_12:45:01
Abc_05-29-2022_12:35:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:30:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:35:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:40:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:20:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:50:01
```

I want to grep selected files from them using bash script and I want to copy those files into some other location:

- Source path : /home/Download/files
- Destination: /home/test

For example, I want to grep files from `abc_29-05-22_12:40:0[1-2]` to `abc_30-05-22_12:20:0[1-2]`.
And copy those files to some other path using shell script

Comment: `grep` is for looking inside files. Do you want to grep these files for a pattern or do you just want to copy some files based on their name, no matter what they contain? Also, you say you want files from `29-05-22_12:40` to `30-05-22_12:20`, but you say your file names are actually in the `05-29-2022_12:40:ss` format. Which one is it?

Comment: I will explain you clearly
For suppose i have 10 files, i want to grep from 3 to 7 files and those files need to copied to some other path
Using bash script for above inputs

Comment: No, please [edit] your question and clarify there.

Comment: Is the path `/home/download/file` or `/home/Download/files`? And is this a directory, or is it a file containing file names?

Comment: File is directory, abc_... are present inside of file

Comment: Is `/home/download/file` a file or a directory? Do you have a file that contains a list of file names, or is this just a directory containing files? And is the right name `/home/download/file` or is it `/home/Download/files`?

Comment: Ls  /home/download/file                                                                                 Abc_05-29-2022_12:30:01
Abc_05-29-2022_12:40:01
Abc_05-29-2022_12:50:02
Abc_05-29-2022_12:45:01
Abc_05-29-2022_12:35:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:30:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:35:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:40:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:20:01
Abc_05-30-2022_12:50:01

Comment: I am asking you two questions: **1.** You mention two different paths in your question: i) `/home/download/file` and ii) `/home/Download/files`.  `Download` and `download` are not the same thing. `file` and `files` are not the same thing, so *which one of the two is correct*? **2.** Do you have a *file* with the name `file` and in that file you have a list of file names? Or do you ave a *directory* named `file` and in that directory you have more files? Can you just show us the output of `ls -l /home/Download/files` or `ls -l /home/download/file`?

Comment: Iam just giving you a random path, i can change names if required

Comment: Can you change the script as read the input date and time and so on excute the script is it possible

Answer (score 1):

A tool like `grep` is not the correct one to select files based on numeric limits (dates). The regex becomes complex and in-maintainable very fast. Some other scripting language is required where number comparisons are possible (not in grep). In this case, `find` isn't the correct tool as it is capable of looking at the modification date but it is difficult to select files based on their names.

Also, there are some inconsistencies on the date format in your question. Is it `day/month/year` (`29-05-22_12:40`) or `month-day-year` (`05-29-2022`)?

And, that format using dash (`-`) instead of slash (`/`) is not understood by the date command (generally).

So, making some adaptations, this script should do what you ask for:

```bash
#!/bin/bash --

dirsource="/home/Download/files"
dirdestin="/home/test"

filestart="$( date -ud '2022/05/29 12:40' +'%s' )"
fileend="$(   date -ud '2022/05/30 12:20' +'%s' )"

while IFS="" read line; do
    IFS="_-" read name month day year time <<<"$line"
    filenow="$(date -ud "$year/$month/$day $time" +"%s")"
    if [[ $filenow -ge $filestart ]] && [[ $filenow -le $fileend ]]; then
        echo \
        mv "$dirsource/$line" "$dirdestin/$line"
    fi
done <./infile
```

Remove the line `echo \` to actually execute the commands when confident it will do what you want.

Comment: I didn't get any output here can you help me here

Answer (score 0):

To copy files whose name represents a date from 2022-05-29T12:40:01 to 2022-05-30T12:20:02 when they have a `Abc_mm-dd-yyyy_HH:MM:SS` format, with zsh (instead of bash) globs, you could do it as:

```
set -o extendedglob
cp /home/download/file/*(e['
  [[ $REPLY:t = (#b)Abc_(<1-12>-<1-31>)-(<->)_(<0-23>:<0-59>:<0-59>) &&
     ${t::=$match[2]-$match[1]T$match[2]} >= 2022-05-29T12:40:01 &&
     $t <= 2022-05-30T12:20:02 ]]']) /home/test/
```

Where we rearrange those timestamps in the standard `yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS` format which can then be compared lexically.

You could also do the checking in a helper function such as:

```
range() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob
  local match t
  [[ $REPLY:t = (#b)*_(<1-12>-<1-31>)-(<->)_(<0-23>:<0-59>:<0-59>) &&
     ${t::=$match[2]-$match[1]T$match[2]} >= $1 && $t <= $2 ]]
}
```

And then:

```
cp /home/download/file/Abc*(e['range 2022-05-29T12:40:01 2022-05-30T12:20:02'])
```